# How to define a vector class using std::array with aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, stl

I define a class like this

```
#include<array>
template<class T,size_t D> 
class vec{
    private:
        std::array<T,D> arr;
    public:
        vec(std::initializer_list<T> l) : arr(l){ }
};
```

Then I construct the object of this class like this.

```
vec<int,3> v = {1,2,3};
```

Then I get an error

```
main.cpp:5:26: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::initializer_list<int>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::initializer_list<int>’
     vec<int,3> v = {1,2,3};
                          ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:
vec.hpp:12:9: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘vec<T, D>::vec(std::initializer_list<_Tp>&) [with T = int; long unsigned int D = 3]’
         vec(std::initializer_list<T>& l) : arr(l){ }
```

I wonder how can I make the aggregated initialization in my constructor valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::array` is not constructable from a `std::initializer_list`.  You have two options to fix this if you want to keep the `std::array` member.  You can make `vec` and aggregate by making `arr` public and removing the constructor like

```
#include<array>
template<class T,size_t D> 
class vec{
    public:
        std::array<T,D> arr;
};

int main()
{
    vec<int,3> v = {1,2,3};
}
```

or you keep it as you have it but instead you iterate over `arr` and assign it values from the initializer list.  That would look like

```
#include<array>
template<class T,size_t D> 
class vec{
    private:
        std::array<T,D> arr;
    public:
        vec(std::initializer_list<T> l)
        {
            std::copy_n(l.begin(), std::min(l.size(), arr.size()), arr.begin());
        }
};

int main()
{
    vec<int,3> v = {1,2,3};
}
```

This method does require the array members to be default constructable.  If you can't/don't want to guarantee that then you need option one or switch to using a different type for `arr` like `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helps. Do you mind explaining more to me about the default constructor? I wonder if I have two std:: array members arr1 and arr2 in class vec, will v={1,2,3} also work? Thank you.

Comment: @Richard In my second example since we are in the body of the constructor that means that `arr` was already default constructed.  In order for that to happen that means `T` needs to be a type that has a default constructor.  If `T` is a type that doesn't have a default constructor then you'll get an error because that means it can't default construct `arr`.  You can you either method for two arrays.  You would just need to use two lists like `vec v = {{1,2,3},{3,4,5}}`

Comment: Yeah, I understand.Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`std::array` does not have any constructors. It has only aggregate initializer. If you replace `std::array` by `std::vector` it should works because vector has initializer list constructor.